# How does a function works

Tags: function, go, syntax, memory-alignment

I'm a beginner in learning Go, and I'm puzzled by the following two questions:

**First**:

```
type S struct{
    a func()
    b func(i int, j float32, k string)
    c *func()
}

func main(){
    s := S{c: &func(){}} // Error: Cannot take the address of `func(){}`
}
```

In this struct, `c *func()` is valid, but `how can I assigned to it`?

**Second**:
As I know, functions are first class citizens, so I can pass function as a parameter to another function/method, also I can declare a function variable, so, `how does a function value works`, does it's actually a function pointer?

I read some articles about alignment and padding, I know a interface value take up 16 bytes(64-bit system) because a interface value is composed of data pointer and type pointer, `what about function value`? I use `unsafe.Sizeof(funcValue)` and it returns 8, so I guess it's actually a function pointer. Is there any way to prove it(right or wrong)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to use the address of a variable that points to this function, you'll need to first assign it to a variable.

```
package main

type S struct {
    a func()
    b func(i int, j float32, k string)
    c *func()
}

func main() {
    c := func() {}
    s := S{c: &c} // No error
}
```

For more information on the inner workings of functions see the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals).

Answer (score 0):

A function literal can be assigned to a variable or invoked directly.

> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.

```
type S struct{
    a func()
    b func(i int, j float32, k string)
    c *func()
}
```

But when you are assigning the function to a variable. you are actually taking the address of `func` which is not a variable. First assign the function to a variable and then you can assign the address of that variable.

```
func main(){
    s := S{c: &func(){}} // Error: Cannot take the address of `func(){}`
}
```

The error is:

> Error: Cannot take the address of `func(){}`

You can only take address of a variable.

```
package main

import ("fmt")

type S struct{
    a func()
    b func(i int, j float32, k string)
    c *func()
}

func main() {
    anonymous := func(){}
    temp := S{c: &anonymous}
    fmt.Println(temp.c)
}
```

Check on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1B-xTWeYVzW)